# Jquery - clicking a combo box and how to fill fields automatically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm working with asp classic and I'm using jqGrid with a pager: I'm managing row data as a result from SQL Server (it works with no problems).
Columns are:

```
id_car | description_of_car | model | plate
```

Now I have to introduce a change to the code because the field "description_of_car" will become a combo box.

Little piece of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({ 
    url:'load_auto.asp',
    ...
    {
        name:'description_of_car',
        index:'description_of_car',
        editable:true,
        editoptions:{readonly:true},
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        width:300,edittype:"select",
        editoptions:{dataUrl:'select_car.asp'}
    },
    ...
    editurl:'edit.asp'
    ...
```

Problem: by selecting the name of an `<option>` I automatically should fill fields "description_of_car", "model" and "plate" in the same pop-up.
Is this possible?

Comment: Which editing mode you use (inline editing, form editing, cell editing)? When the fields "description_of_car", "model" and "plate" should be filled (after saving the row/cell or directly during editing in onchange of select `description_of_car`)? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: I'm using form editing managed by file edit.asp
Fields 'model' and 'plate' should be filled  during editing in onchange of select description_of_car.

I downloaded Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.0.1